# Source of this warning: dnssdclientstub:sdRef: CallbackwithError morebytes zero sdr

Tags: ios, networking, warnings

I am noticing the following warning in the console for my iOS app. Is this warning familiar to anyone and should I be concerned about it appearing in my console?

> : dnssdclientstub:sdRef: CallbackwithError morebytes zero sdr
>   0x15e55520

It seems that it might be a warning that precedes an intermittent issue where my app will not resume after having been dormant in the background.

I see this log message in a file 'dnssd_clientstub.c', but I'm not directly including this file in my code and assume that it is something in the lower level networking codebase.

Here is a link to that file:
http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/mDNSResponder/mDNSResponder-320.10/mDNSShared/dnssd_clientstub.c

Thank you in advance for any info you can provide!

Comment: I'm seeing this warning too. Not sure what it is but I'm just going to ignore it :P